# Are HDR movies in cinemas displayed in linear colorspace?

Tags: film, dynamic-range

It seems to me that a projector using a bright enough light source should be capable of displaying a HDR picture without the need to do any tone mapping. A  transparency can have an opacity ranging from 0% to 100% (obviously, it's no problem to completely block the light source) and the intensity of the light source is virtually limitless. So, I was wondering if HDR movies projected on a screen are displaying the (16 or 32 bit) linear files directly?

Answer (score 3):

The bad thing about projector is that it differs from just a high power light source by having an absorber - film in the past, LCD or something similar nowadays. It means that it can't have massively larger contrast ratio and it also can't make very bright output because it means that the absorver would overheat when showing dark screen. The absence of limit of light source is useless because the absorber would need to absorb large amount of that energy and yet the contrast ratio will be as poor as it is already.

More about this [here](http://www.cnet.com/news/dlp-vs-lcd-vs-lcos-projector-tech-pros-and-cons/), for example.

It is possible to increase contrast ratio of projectors by using AMOLED as light source combined with fast objective (possible in the future) but it is still far away from requiring anything much more than gamma2.2 24bit.

ALso, linear coding is not anything useful because you can achieve same percepted bit depth using [LogLUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logluv_TIFF) with much fewer bits.

> So, I was wondering if HDR movies projected on a screen are displaying the (16 or 32 bit) linear files directly?

Nope, no miracles this time.